# Conditions in WHERE clause in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am newbie to couchbase. Cannot find online what I am trying to achieve.

I am trying to use condition for specific document type. My condition will be like this - if document type is 'type1' then find specific id in that document and document type 'type2' then find another id in that document type only. My query is like below -

```
SELECT DISTINCT appDetail.id, appDetail.group_id_record
FROM default appDetail
LEFT JOIN default users ON KEYS appDetail.id
LEFT JOIN default groups ON KEYS ARRAY 'app_detail::' || TO_STRING(c) FOR c 
IN appDetail.group_id_record END
WHERE (appDetail.type = 'user' OR appDetail.type = 'app_detail')
```

I assume I need additional condition in JOIN may be?

Comment: See CASE expressions for conditional expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [CASE conditional operator](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/conditionalops.html)

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE  WHEN appDetail.type = 'user' THEN appDetail.id WHEN appDetail.type = 'app_detail' THEN appDetail.detailId END, appDetail.group_id_record
FROM default appDetail
LEFT JOIN default users ON KEYS appDetail.id
LEFT JOIN default groups ON KEYS ARRAY 'app_detail::' || TO_STRING(c) FOR c 
IN appDetail.group_id_record END
WHERE (appDetail.type = 'user' OR appDetail.type = 'app_detail')
```

Be carefull with DISTINCT in your query because you group same id although the type is different (I don't think you want this result)